# Infinte loop is killing my NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js

As the title says, I think my server can't handle the speed of calculations of the infinite loop, how would I make it so the calculations still go very quick but the server doesn't crash? also when I try this in jsfiddle it eventually crashes my browser.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
function crashPoint(){
    var currentTry = 2;
        var mainMultplier = 1;
        var secMultiplier = Math.random();

    for(;;){
      var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

      if(1/currentTry*100 < randomInt){
        currentTry = currentTry+1;
        mainMultplier = mainMultplier+1;
      }else{
        console.clear();
        break;
      }
  }

  var totalMultiplier = mainMultplier+secMultiplier;

  if(totalMultiplier > 2){
    totalMultiplier-1;
  }

  console.log("Crashed @ " + totalMultiplier.toFixed(2));
}
</script>

<button onclick="crashPoint()">
Try me!
</button>
```

Kind regards.

Comment: Might have better luck with WebWorkers.

Comment: All the calculations need to be done in a fraction of a second tho

Comment: @blex it will always be the case sometimes, if you check how the code works it will eventually stop.

Comment: `setInterval(<function>, 1)`?

Comment: @jack wouldn't this just delay the loop and then make it crash

Comment: Also `randomInt` will *always* be more than 1, so it will never be less than `1/currentTry*100`, which is your break condition.

Comment: Due to integer division, I think maybe you want: `if ((100 / currentTry) < ...`

Comment: @blex Thank you so much for your anwser, I just had to remove the multiply by 100 because ofcourse once it will go under 1 and then it wouldn't be able to break the loop anymore.

Comment: @Jack I figured, thanks ;)

Comment: This loop is useless. If you want to give some delay for other code - it never get control, js is one-threaded.

Comment: I see no crash here

Comment: What is the point of this code?  The best solution would be to find a better way to solve your problem that doesn't hog the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/currentTry*100 won't always stay an integer, randomInt will, I just had to make it so randomInt wasn't always an integer anymore which I could do by removing the *100.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use setInterval instead of a loop... just call the same function however many times per second you need it to execute.

Comment: This isn't an answer and should be deleted. Once you get 50 rep points ( easy to obtain with some editing and voting) you can use comment blocks to ask for clarification

Comment: The above does attempt to answer the question. Granted, it is probably not the best approach to the problem ...